# Second video recording with UIImagePickerController override the path of first video recording

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to record two videos with `UIImagePickerController`. Everything is working fine but while recording the second video seems it override the Path of first recorded video.
I need to upload both videos to the server but first video path got nil while uploading and app got crashed. Is there any way to record the second video at different path?

Video Path as follows:

1. `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1465EC90-4B57-41FF-996E-0CCB7713ECE7/tmp/50332801315__A883E4DB-ED72-4D31-9564-22FB363779BD.MOV`
2. `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1465EC90-4B57-41FF-996E-0CCB7713ECE7/tmp/50332802324__F11733AD-EB62-426D-BA1C-7E87D2BF66D0.MOV`

Here is my `imagePicker` delegate code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
    NSURL *videoUrl = (NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
    }

    NSLog(@"videoUrl: %@", videoUrl);
    NSLog(@"moviePath: %@", moviePath);

    // self.moviePath_1 = @"";
    // self.moviePath_2 = @"";

    NSLog(@"picker.title: %@", picker.title);
    if ([picker.title isEqualToString:@"Video_1"]) {
        self.moviePath_1 = moviePath;
        self.video_1 = YES;
        NSLog(@"self.moviePath_1: %@", self.moviePath_1);
        self.video_1_Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.moviePath_1]];
        NSLog(@"Video_1 Size: %@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:self.video_1_Data.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);

        [self setupAndPlayback:@"Video_1"];

    } else {
        self.moviePath_2 = moviePath;
        self.video_2 = YES;
        NSLog(@"self.moviePath_2: %@", self.moviePath_2);
        self.video_2_Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.moviePath_2]];
        NSLog(@"Video_2 Size: %@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:self.video_2_Data.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);

        [self setupAndPlayback:@"Video_2"];

    }
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save Video on different Paths. You are overriding the same path that why this issue is happen. Add Time Stamp or increasing Number with Path and save it.

```
 self.moviePath_1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%d.png", moviePath, num] ;
 num += 1; // for next time
```